# Angular Material Slider - allow minimum value without disabling the slider

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material slider in my angular project which I want to have a value between 200 and 5000.

I set the min value to 200. 200 is a valid value. However, when I slide the slider to 200, it disables itself as if the value is invalid.

Any idea how to disable this behaviour?

Slider:

```
<mat-slider min="200"
            max="5000"
            step="100"
            [value]="200"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: You need to override the `.mat-slider-min-value` class for this. Or use the cdk-slider

Comment: Oh, well that works!

Comment: Yep, they are very strict with the material library to comply with the defined material standard. So you need to override classes, or use the cdk, with which you can create and style your own slider

Comment: should add this comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the slider is not disabled but the color is set to grey for an unknown reason.

I solved with the following lines:

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-slider.mat-slider-min-value.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing.cdk-focused .mat-slider-thumb-label {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
      background-color: mat-color($my-app-primary);
    }

    ::ng-deep .mat-slider.mat-slider-min-value.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing .mat-slider-thumb {
      background-color: mat-color($my-app-primary);
    }
```